# How heightFactor and widthFactor works?

Tags: flutter

I am reading docs about [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget and can't figure out how height\width factors are working?

> If non-null, sets its height to the child's height multiplied by this factor

[image]

I expected that size of button will be multiplied to height\width factor. I tried specify it's size explicitly, but did not get success.

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
            height: 280,
            width: 280,
            child: Align(
                heightFactor: 8,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hello",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ))),
        // child: Text("Hello"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: try this: 
 heightFactor: 0.8,

Comment: @MaadhavSharma I tried without any result

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned for the Align widget if heightFactor is non-null then the corresponding dimension of this widget will be the product of the child’s measurement and the size factor. For example, if heightFactor is 2.0 then the height of Align will always be twice its child’s height.

I recommend you use FractionallySizedBox instead of Align to set the button's width and height manually:

```
       SizedBox(
                height: 280,
                width: 280,
                child:
                    FractionallySizedBox(
                      heightFactor: 0.5,
                      widthFactor: 0.5,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Hello",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () => {},
                            ),
                          ),
                    
              ),
```